# IBM Bluemix keeps asking for credentials

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

i am trying to push a local image into my bluemix repo. I already choosed the right API, region, installed the cf plugins, logged in into my org.. double checked everything. But when I try to

```
docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/path/path/imagename:latest
```

the preparing process starts but aborts with

```
no basic auth credentials
```

What can I do to avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: what is the `/path/path/` you are refering to? as far as i can see in the official documentation the correct way to push a docker image is `docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/<my_namespace>/<image_name>` where the namespace is the one you gave when you created the public registry on bluemix.

Comment: The /path/path is my workingenviroment eg /companyname/dev . Is it possbile that the double / causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Did all steps from scratch and suddenly I am able to push containers in my repo :) but I can't really say, what the porblem was.. anyway, thanks for the help to anyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command and then login again and then see if it helps -

```
cf ic init
```

You might need to do it occasionally when you face this problem..